# Approval Page not showing after new user registered [laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm setting up a page for registration.  What I made so far is when a new users registers, they will get an email verification.  After they verify their email, they will go to an approval page and will need to wait until admin approves their account.

The problem is when a new user is registered, the admin does not receive the approval email notification and the admin page does not show every new user that has been registered.  It's just showing "welcome admin".

Laravel Version: `7.19.0`

Here is my `app/User.php`:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
...
 protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'admin', 'approved_at',
    ];
```

Here is my `routes/web.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function (){
    Route::get('/approval', 'HomeController@approval')->name('approval');
    
    Route::middleware(['approved'])->group(function (){
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    });
    Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function (){
        Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index')->name('admin.users.index');
        Route::get('/users/{user_id}/approve', 'UserController@approve')->name('admin.users.approve');
    });    
});
```

Here is my `app/Notifications/NewUser.php`:

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NewUser extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    
    private $new_user;

    public function __construct(User $new_user)
    {
        $this->new_user = $new_user;
    }

   /*  public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    } */

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('New user has registered with email'.$this->new_user->email)
                    ->action('Approve User', route('admin.users.approve', $this->new_user->id));
                    /* ->line('this page is restricted!'); */
    }
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is my `app/Http/kernel.php`:

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
...
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'approved' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckApproved::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdmin::class,
    ];
```

Here is my `.env`:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mail
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=title
MAIL_FROM_NAME=appname
```

I also have two files in `app/http/middleware`:

1. CheckedApproved
2. CheckAdmin

Comment: Are there any errors in the storage/logs directory?

Comment: i don't see any error on page or in storage/log directory